# Is it efficient to create multiple keys pointing to the same object?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, pass-by-reference

I have an array of countries, where each country have three properties.

```
const countries = [
  { name: "Poland", alpha: "POL", code: "616" },
  { name: "Hungary", alpha: "HUN", code: "348" },
  // and so on...
]
```

Later on I want to easily access each country by any of these properties.

I was thinking of reducing this array to an object that would have three keys for each country pointing to the very same country object.

Something like this:

```
const countriesObject = countries.reduce((object, country) => {
  const { name, alpha, code } = country;

  // Create individual country object
  object[name] = { ...country };

  // Reference just created country object 
  object[code] = object[name];
  object[alpha] = object[name];

  return object;
});
```

In the end I could access each country object either by its name, code or alpha.

```
countriesObject["Poland"] // → 
countriesObject["POL"]    // → The same object
countriesObject["616"]    // →
```

**My question is, would it be considered good practice, or there are some better ways to achieve the same or similar result?**

Thank you!

Comment: This sounds like a premature optimisation to me

Comment: So storing these countries as an array and getting each country for example with `.find()` method would be fine?

Comment: I would say tentatively yes, best approach is to measure actual performance

Comment: These look like ISO3166-1 country codes. If that is the case, there are currently 249 countries with defined codes. All names, alphas and codes are unique and don't change that often, so why not simply define the variables within a static js file and load that when needed, rather than create them on-the-fly in each HTML page that uses them? But, I'm with sitek94 - why not simply use `.find()`? How often are you going to need to find the value from a variable instead the array because you don't know whether it's a name, alpha or code value? Why doesn't the rest of the code/page supply that bit?

Comment: @ATD "_why not simply define the variables within a static js file and load that when needed_" I've been going in circles where the solution was so simple. I made a static file and it's perfect for my needs. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's fine, as all of those keys, as you correctly noted, will be pointing to the same object. The biggest problem that I see here is that it's easy to reduce readability of the code by using this approach. Let's say we have this fragment:

```
console.log( countriesObject[id] );
```

The question is, what is id here? Is it full country name? or just alpha? or code? You might just not care, true, but if you do, consider giving them additional structure:

```
const countriesObject = countries.reduce((object, country) => {
  const { name, alpha, code } = country;
  const countryCopy = { ...country };

  // it makes sense to place them on the same line to show the intent
  object.name[name] = object.code[code] = object.alpha[alpha] = countryCopy;
  return object;
}, { name: {}, code: {}, alpha: {} });
```

Another potential issue is that you won't be able to drop the countries easily from this object; it's not enough to delete just a single key pointing to it, you'll have to go and remove all three. But that doesn't seem to be a big thing here; this looks more like a dictionary.

Comment: I see what you mean. I'm not worried about the second issue, because it's just as you said: "more like a dictionary", but I really haven't thought about readability and now I see that there is a problem. I think I'll create another property `id` and throughout the app I'll access the countries by their ids.

Comment: `object.name[name] = object.code[code] = object.alpha[alpha] = countryCopy`, awesome, I didn't know I can use assignment operator like this. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed write it like this:

```
var countries = {[
  "poland": {
     alpha: "POL", code: "616"
  },
  "hungary": {
     alpha: "HUN", code: "348"
  }
]}
```

Accessing each country like this:

```
var poland = countries.poland;
```

This, in turn, produces more readable code:

```
var alpha = countries.poland.alpha;
```

instead of

```
var alpha = countries[0].alpha;
```

But there is no set preference.

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)